# Performance difference between NOT Exists and LEFT JOIN IN SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can have following query in order to check existing of record in target table.

```
Select * 
From Table1
Where Column1 not in (select Column2 from Table2)

Select *
from Table1
left join Table2 where Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column2
Where Table2.IdColumn is Null
```

I want to know which query has better performance.

Comment: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: Have you already checked the query execution plan? - http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2250/graphical-query-plan-tutorial/

Comment: @Gidil. You'd need to find a SQL Server duplicate as the answer is optimiser dependant.

Comment: Reopened. This is implementation dependant. And therefore not a duplicate of a teradata question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go for `NOT EXISTS` generally.

It is [more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists/11074428#11074428) than `NOT IN` if the columns on either side are nullable (and has the semantics you probably desire anyway)

Left join ... Null sometimes does the whole join with a later filter to preserve the rows matching the `is null` and can be much less efficient.

An example demonstrating this is below. Notice the extra operators in the `NOT IN` plan and how the outer join plan blows up to create a join of over 1 million rows going into the filter.

### Not Exists

[image]

### Outer Join ... NULL

[image]

### Not In

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
     IdColumn INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
     Column1  INT NULL,
     Filler   CHAR(8000) NULL,
     UNIQUE(Column1, IdColumn) );

CREATE TABLE Table2 (
     IdColumn INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
     Column2  INT NULL,
     Filler   CHAR(8000) NULL,
     UNIQUE(Column2, IdColumn) );

INSERT INTO Table2 (Column2)
OUTPUT      INSERTED.Column2
INTO Table1(Column1)
SELECT number % 5
FROM   master..spt_values

SELECT *
FROM   Table1 t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   Table2 t2
                   WHERE  t2.Column2 = t1.Column1)

SELECT *
FROM   Table1
WHERE  Column1 NOT IN (SELECT Column2
                       FROM   Table2)

SELECT Table1.*
FROM   Table1
       LEFT JOIN Table2
         ON Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column2
WHERE  Table2.IdColumn IS NULL

DROP TABLE Table1, Table2
```